# JS check if getElementById exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is part of my class homework. It is a small web application. The code part below is a function for a select button (checkbox). The code is working fine.

My issue is I get this error on console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null
>       at selectGirls (indexj.js:163)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (index.html:137)

I know I get this error because, I haven't these elements on every page. To clarify that, I mean page 1 has two checkboxes, but page 2 has 5 checkboxes, like that.

I want to use this same JS file for all pages. My question is how can I avoid these console errors best way possible? I do not want to make them hide from console as a solution. I really appreciate your input.

```js
function selectAllStudents() {
    unselectAllStudents();
    let boxes = $(".scores").toArray();
    document.getElementById('check_Terrilyn').checked = true;
    document.getElementById('check_Vinnie').checked = true;
    document.getElementById('check_Boren').checked = true;
    document.getElementById('check_Tempie').checked = true;
    document.getElementById('check_Mapes').checked = true;
    document.getElementById('check_Fletcher').checked = true;
    document.getElementById('check_Bovee').checked = true;
    document.getElementById('check_Figgs').checked = true;
}
```

Comment: If you're setting them all to a checked state, then select them by `class` and loop through them all. That way it won't matter if none are found.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The simplest is to check if they are there

```
if (document.getElementById('check_Terrilyn'))
  document.getElementById('check_Terrilyn').checked = true;
```

**Edit**

A more modern approach, and given that there are an unknown amount of checkboxes, could be to use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

It will return a list of elements ([NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)), and e.g., and as your code suggest, all the checkeboxes's `id` starts with `check_`, you can use it like this with an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="check_"]');
els.forEach(function (el) {
    el.checked = true;
});
```

```html
<input id="check_0" type="checkbox" value="0">
<input id="check_1" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input id="check_2" type="checkbox" value="2">
<input id="check_3" type="checkbox" value="3">
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm gonna try this now.

Comment: Given you have to do this N times for each checkbox and repeat the `getElementById()` call, I wouldn't call it the 'simplest'.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What is 'simplest' depends on which side of the fence you are :) ... in this case I simply wanted to show _a way of thinking_, and decided to keep the already used plain js code. The code itself can of course be optimized in many ways.

Comment: @LGSon, may I ask you to have a look at a jQuery related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468968/jquery-click-at-a-co-ordinate-on-an-image-and-draw-a-circle-there ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Won't be able now...just hang in there and someone will come to rescue :)

Answer (score 5):

### Approach with id and if

```
if (document.getElementById('check_Terrilyn')){
    document.getElementById('check_Terrilyn').checked = true;
}
```

### Approach with classes

```
//ES6
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('commonclass')).forEach(e => {
    e.checked = true;
});
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array. Trying to set the `checked` property of an array will cause an error

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan actually it returns a HTMLCollection, not an array.

Answer (score 2):

I use to do

```
if(document.getElementById('check_Terrilyn')!="null")
    document.getElementById('check_Terrilyn').checked=true;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do somewhat like this:

```
let elm = document.getElementById('check_Terrilyn');

elem && elem.checked = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you're already using jQuery. Why not use it fully, and stop using `getElementById` ?

Just do `$( ... ).prop('checked',true)`. jQuery will handle the case where the element is not found.

```
function selectAllStudents() {
    unselectAllStudents();
    let boxes = $(".scores").toArray();
    $('#check_Terrilyn, #check_Vinnie, #check_Boren, #check_Tempie, #check_Mapes, #check_Fletcher, #check_Bovee, #check_Figgs').prop('checked',true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting them all to a checked state, then select them by `class` and loop through them all. That way it won't matter if none are found.

You also appear to be using jQuery, so the code can then be simplified to just:

```
function selectAllStudents() {
  unselectAllStudents();
  let boxes = $(".scores").toArray();
  $('.checkbox').prop('checked', true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged jquery, use `prop`

```
function selectAllStudents() {
    unselectAllStudents();
    let boxes = $(".scores").toArray();
    $('#check_Terrilyn').prop( "checked", true );
    //for the rest of them
}
```

Or create an array of ids which you can iterate and check if they exists before setting their `checked` property

```
var array = ['check_Terrilyn', 'check_Vinnie']; //add more ids as required
array.forEach( s => $("#"+s).prop( "checked", true ) );
```

Or with plain js

```
var array = ['check_Terrilyn', 'check_Vinnie']; //add more ids as required
var fnGetEl = (id) => document.getElemetById(id);
array.forEach( s => {
  var el = fnGetEl(s);
  if(el)
  {
    el.checked = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementById("id_selector2teller")){
alert("id_selector2teller exists");
}else{
alert("id_selector2teller not available");
}
```

Comment: please be more specific with your anwser and add some explanation.

Comment: When adding an answer to an older question with many existing answers it is very important to add some explanation of how and why your answer works as well as pointing out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses.

Answer (score 0):

This works if you want to check if element exists and at the same time assign it to a variable (and make it 'false' if the element doesn't exist):

```
var check_Terrilyn = document.getElementById('check_Terrilyn') ?
                     document.getElementById('check_Terrilyn').checked : false;
```