# jQuery- click at a co-ordinate on an image and draw a circle there

Tags: jquery, click, position, overlay

I have a `div` namely `image_preview` with an image inside it. There is an input box to get the radius of the circle from the user. When I click at a point on the image, I need a circle with that point as the center and the radius input as the radius. The circle should be marked with a marker . The `div` with id `hotspot_display` works as the marker and the `div` `circle` acts as the circle to be displayed . Both are absolutely positioned. The marker  has as its background an image with the dimension 24X24.

Whenever I click,  clones of the marker and circle are made and positioned around the point I clicked. The marker and circle positions are changed with mouse click (You'll find the fiddle link  at the end of this question).

I can capture the co-ordinate of the point at which I click with `offset` and `clientX` etc. the code for which follows:

**HTML:**
    Image:

```
<input type="text" value="0"  class="radius" name="radius"/>

<div id="image_preview">

    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/B7VsSq3.png" alt="background" />



    <div id="hotspot_display"></div>

    <div class="circle" style="background-color: #858585; position: absolute;"></div>

</div><!-- end of id image_preview-->

<div id="hotspot_answer_points">


</div><!-- end of id hotspot_answer_points-->
```

**JS:**

```
   $('#image_preview').bind('click', function (ev) {

                var $div = $(ev.target);
                var $div = $(this);
                var $display =  $('#image_preview').find('#hotspot_display');
                var offset_t = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
                var offset_l = $(this).offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft();

                var left = Math.round( (ev.clientX - offset_l) );
                var top = Math.round( (ev.clientY - offset_t) );

                if(window.console){

                    console.log("left = "+left+" top = "+top);

                }


                var display_clone=$display.clone().show();
                display_clone.css({'top':top+33,'left':left+10,'display':'block'});

});
```

The code of `display_clone.css` has in its parameter some values (33 and 10 ) added to `left` and `top` without which I cannot get the center of  image marker sit just on the co-ordinate.

**Question 1)** I just randomly used the 33 and 10 values to be added. What  calculation  should really be done here as these numbers to be added might vary If my HTML code sits inside a complex HTML page?

**Question 2**: I cannot get the circle's center to be the co-ordinate I clicked . What should be the way here ?

The whole of the scenario is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jsf_user/jcs9btaw/6/) in a fiddle.

**EDIT:**
My scenario has actually 2 parts. The situation stated above takes place in an admin area. In the user area , I again show the image inside a `div` namely `hotspot_user_area`. I saved the clicked co-ordinates in database from the admin area. In user I area, I have the HTML:

```
<div id="hotspot_user_area">

<img src="https://i.imgur.com/B7VsSq3.png" alt="background" />

</div>
```

I take the co-ordinates from database and want to show them with markers in the `hotspot_user_area` on the image. Suppose I get the co-ordinate from DB  to be in variable `x1` and `y1`; Now if I use the following code from **Roko C. Buljan**'s answer , it won't work :

```
 $("<div />", {
      "class": "circle",
      css: {
        top: y1,
        left: x1,
        width: r * 2,
        height: r * 2,
      },
      appendTo: $this // append to #image_preview!
    }).
```

This doesn;t work because in admin panel `left` and `top` properties have the values `x` and `y` respectively which have the following calculation:

```
y = ev.pageY - o.top,
x = ev.pageX - o.left;
```

So how can I place the markers at the same place of the image in whatever `div` the image is placed again ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simpler approach:

- To get the center use something like `ev.pageX - el.offset().left`
- Don't clone elements. Create them on the fly.
- Use CSS `transform translate` to center them

```js
var App = App || {};
App.points = []; // Use array to store objects like [{x,y,r}, {x,y,r} ...]


jQuery(function($) {

  const $radius = $(".radius");

  $('#image_preview').on('click', function(ev) {

    const $this = $(this),
       r = parseInt($radius.val().trim(), 10), // Parse as Integer radix 10
      o = $this.offset(),
      y = ev.pageY - o.top,
      x = ev.pageX - o.left;

    $("<div />", {
      "class": "circle",
      css: {
        top: y,
        left: x,
        width: r * 2,
        height: r * 2,
      },
      appendTo: $this // append to #image_preview!
    });

    // Append data to App.points
    App.points.push({x,y,r});
    // Test
    console.log( App.points )

  });

});
```

```css
#image_preview {
  position: relative; /* Add this since child are absolute! */
  background: #eee;
  margin: 15px;
  cursor: crosshair;
}

#image_preview img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2) url("https://i.imgur.com/qtpC8Rf.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* use translate instead of JS calculations */
}

.radius {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
Radius: <input type="text" value="20" class="radius" name="radius">

<div id="image_preview">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/B7VsSq3.png" alt="graph">
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Much simpler, that 's a fact. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, I added an 'EDIT:'. BTW I don't see the answer you gave here !.

Comment: @Roko, I added an 'EDIT:'

Comment: can you explain what you did by `y = ev.pageY - o.top` ?

Comment: I think the `EDIT` I added will further elaborate my extra question

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed you should store in your database the real absolute center coords. Not some translated center that depends on some width / height. Take (again) 
 a closer look at my example to get an idea.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, I tried to understand. I guess I need the absolute co-ordinate wrt to the image itself i.e. the top left corner of the image being (0,0), right ? Other wise in another page  with the same image, previously stored co-ordinates might not work. Cannot find any way to implement it. Do you have any ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, `y = ev.pageY - o.top` - it does not give the absolute co-ordinate ( where the top left of the image is )0,0)) of the image itself right, ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed sorry, could you please run my example and point what is not working with my example? I cannot get what you don't understand from the code I provided.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed as you can see from my example, all you need to store into your database are `x, y, r` (where `r` stands for **radius**.) So, no width and height to bother with. The elements translations are achieved using CSS. Read all over again my answer for inclarities.

Comment: Have you seen `console.log( App.points )` in my code? Those are the values you can store in DB.